# Traducción de modelo Android a Swift

Tags: ios, swift

En mi lado del servidor, desarrollado con ASP.NET tengo una clase que me permite manejar información adicional y cuenta con variables de tipo `Object` para que su uso sea genérico. Esta se muestra a continuación.

```
public class Extra
{
    public Object key1;
    public Object key2;
    public Object key3;
    public Object key4;
}
```

En el lado del cliente tengo una app Android y una iOS desarrolladas con lenguaje nativo. Para manejar la información en la app Android tengo una clase simular como se muestra a continuación (con sus respectivos get y set, se omite para simplificar).

```
public class Extra implements Serializable 
{
    private Object key1;
    private Object key2;
    private Object key3;
    private Object key4;
}
```

Cuando arriba del servidor un objeto de este tipo, con la ayuda de la librería GSON deserializado y puedo a su ves transformar cada variable en el tipo de objeto necesario.

```
JsonObject root = data.getAsJsonObject();
String referencia = new Gson().fromJson(root.get("key1"),String.class);
producto.setProductos_x_impuestos(Arrays.asList(new Gson().fromJson(root.get("key2"), ProductoImpuestos[].class)));
```

Cabe acotar que las variables de esta clase son opcionales, es decir en ocasiones se puede tener información en solo en el key1, otras en el key2 y key3 o en otras todas. Mi duda es como replicar eso en Swift, en intentado con lo siguiente.

```
class Extra: NSObject {
var key1: AnyClass?
var key2: AnyClass?
var key3: AnyClass?
var key4: AnyClass?

init(key1: AnyClass?, key2: AnyClass?, key3: AnyClass?, key4: AnyClass?) {
    self.key1 = key1
    self.key2 = key2
    self.key3 = key3
    self.key4 = key4
}

func getDictionary() -> NSMutableDictionary{
    let data = NSMutableDictionary()
    data.setValue(self.key1, forKey: "key1")
    data.setValue(self.key2, forKey: "key2")
    data.setValue(self.key3, forKeyPath: "key3")
    data.setValue(self.key4, forKeyPath: "key4")
    return data
}
}
```

Sin embargo no logro deserializar los objetos que llegan del servidor e incluso me genera un error debido a que algunos de los parámetros llegan en null (Nil).

Agredezco sus sugerencias.

Comment: Tienes agregado en el .plist el atributo **Allow Arbitrary Loads** en `true`?

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que utilices el protocolo `Decodable` previsto por Apple para decodificar tus objetos. De la siguiente manera:

```
class Extra: Decodable {
    var key1: AnyObject?
    var key2: AnyObject?
    var key3: AnyObject?
    var key4: AnyObject?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        key1 = try container.decode(AnyObject.self, forKey: .key1)
        key2 = try container.decode(AnyObject.self, forKey: .key2)
        key3 = try container.decode(AnyObject.self, forKey: .key3)
        key4 = try container.decode(AnyObject.self, forKey: .key4)
   }
}
```

Luego, en tu clase servicio donde recibes el json en bruto, puedes decodificarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) (Puedes utilizar `guard` aquí)
let extra = JSONDecoder().decode(Extra.self, from: jsonData)
```

También te recomiendo que utilices tipos de datos específicos, mas que "AnyObject".

Saludos.